# The difference between Mono C# Compiler and MS C# Compiler Regarding Scope

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, compiler-construction, mono, compiler-errors

I'm running in a corner case here with regarding the difference with scoping of instance methods/properties in C#. Here is the code:

```
public class Base
{
   public EventHandler Click {get;set;}
   public Base(EventHandler clickHandler)
   {
      this.Click = clickHandler;
   }
}

public class Derived: Base
{
   public Derived(): base((sender, e) => Execute())
   {
   }

   private void Execute()
   {
   }
}
```

The code compiles fine on MonoDevelop 3.0, but gives an error in VS2010 saying:
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property "Base.Execute"
Basically, it boils down to the fact that when calling base class's constructor from derived class's constructor, MS's C# compiler does not allow access to derived class's methods/properties, etc. How so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The VS compiler follows the specification. Not sure what is the reason it is allowed in Mono implemetation.

[C# Specification](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx), section 10.11.1 Constructor initializers:

> An instance constructor initializer cannot access the instance being created. Therefore it is a compile-time error to reference this in an argument expression of the constructor initializer, as is it a compile-time error for an argument expression to reference any instance member through a simple-name.

Comment: Sounds to me like it's just a bug in Mono. I suspect it's easy to represent in IL - it's a purely C# restriction.

Comment: I'm thinking why this restriction though, is it because that when calling base class constructor, the derived class is not initialized yet and therefore can not access its instance member?

Comment: One can easily access "this" inside constructor (including base one - i.e. virtual functions of derived class will be called). I think the reason is that using this at that point will be subject to very strange restrictions and unrelated changes (i.e. move field initializtion from declaration to a constructor) could change behavior of the code.

Comment: Indeed - it's basically the same reason that calling a virtual method from a constructor is usually a bad idea.